# Permission error on angular build

Tags: angularjs, build

Using Win 8 and tried git bash, powershell and cmd as administrator as described @ [angular.org](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/contribute) but I get this EPERM on every `bower install` attempt

```
bower extract       closure-compiler#* compiler-20130603.zip
bower EPERM         EPERM, rename 'C:\Users\Attila\AppData\Roaming\bower\cache\p
ackages\67772d798104a767e90491171870a089\_wildcard'

Stack trace:
Error: EPERM, rename 'C:\Users\Attila\AppData\Roaming\bower\cache\packages\67772
d798104a767e90491171870a089\_wildcard'

Console trace:
Trace
    at StandardRenderer.error (c:\Users\Attila\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
bower\lib\renderers\StandardRenderer.js:74:17)
    at Logger.updateNotifier.packageName (c:\Users\Attila\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\bower\bin\bower:109:18)
    at Logger.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Logger.emit (c:\Users\Attila\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_
modules\bower-logger\lib\Logger.js:29:39)
    at c:\Users\Attila\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\commands\insta
ll.js:27:16
    at _rejected (c:\Users\Attila\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_mo
dules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at c:\Users\Attila\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.j
s:834:30
    at Promise.when (c:\Users\Attila\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node
_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (c:\Users\Attila\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at c:\Users\Attila\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.j
s:574:44

System info:
Bower version: 1.2.8
Node version: 0.10.24
OS: Windows_NT 6.2.9200 x64
```

Comment: Did find a solution? I have recently upgraded my node modules and my bower components and I can't build my app now

Comment: @pilau nope... I've just gave up and build it on my arch linux box.

Comment: I have discovered it was the cdnify grunt task breaking, so I disabled it for now. Unfortunately couldn't find anything about this bug regarding cdnify. I will post an issue on their repo